# git get previous revision number

Tags: git

I'm trying to get short stats between two git revisions (the current one with the previous one)
I have the following command

```
git diff --shortstat -b -w <SHA1 of starting commit>..<SHA1 of ending commit>
```

How can I elegantly and automatically specify the ending commit as the direct previous one to the starting commit I specifoed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you append a `^` to a commit, you can get its parent:

```
$ git show HEAD^       # Show parent of latest commit
$ git show 9dd206a^    # Show parent of 9dd206a
```

The [gitrevisions](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) man page has a *lot* more details on all the different ways to specify commits.

Answer (score 1):

Try git diff --shortstat -b -w HEAD^

Comment: that gives me the same data but inversed, the value of insertions goes in deletions and vice versa... how can I get actual changes from previous to now

Comment: diff --shortstat -b -w ^HEAD ?